# Hosting that scales with mobile app growth?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, hosting, lamp

I'm looking for a host that can scale with the growth of my app from a shared plan to semi-shared to dedicated to multi dedicated, all with only a call and upgrade in plan, no serious re-config on my part. Must support PHP, mySQL minimally, which most do, but also include reasonable headroom on bandwidth and storage - preferably unlimited, but I know I may be dreaming there - and also the ability to install php libraries if necessary (I must have imagemagick). Oh and Cpanel is a must. I don't want to have to manage from the command line, or even manage the OS environment at all for that matter. Why should I tweak and patch when I should be moving my app forward?

Any of you launched your apps with a host that comes close to this, or any of you know who to stay away from in this regard? I'm with Hostmonster now and they have no dedicated plan and already cut me off during my testing phase for hitting their mySQL server too heavy. There's no way I can launch on their shared plan knowing this. My app is also social, heavily integrated with Facebook and Twitter, and free, so my user base could grow as rapid as it's shared with others. I need to be able to respond to growth quickly, but don't want to overspend initially. This is a bootstrapped effort, so I must be conservative but prepared.

Comment: Get a VPS from a reputable supplier and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Rackspace Cloud Computing](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/).  The prices are reasonable and scaling the server in the manner you are interested in should be relatively painless.  If you're at a point where you're even considering this sort of scaling you're probably ready to be done with shared hosting anyway.

Shared hosting is fine for a small site with relatively light traffic, but is probably not sufficient for your needs.

Granted, you'll have to take matters into your hands with regards to setting up the server and installing whatever you need, but you're going to have to face these facts eventually (and there is plenty of help available out there to help you along).